# RHEL 6: service ntpd status ntpd dead but pid file exists

Tags: linux, rhel, ntp, ntpd

I am trying to start the ntpd service.
Because the NTP status is `service ntpd status ntpd dead but PID file exists` I tried to kill the ntpd process.
After trying `ps -ef | grep ntpd` and unable to find the service process PID I removed the PID file and the lock file:

`/var/run/ntpd.pid, /var/lock/subsys/ntpd`
(the pid in the pid file is also not exist)

After removing the files the service status is stopped but after starting the service the pid and lock file create again and the status is still `service ntpd status ntpd dead but PID file exists`

Comment: It looks like that after you start ntpd it crashes and leaves PID file undeleted. I guess you have to find why that happens. Search for clues in logs or start ntpd with the default configuration.